# Iterate inside multiple tables

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have a HTML in the format of this

```
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test1 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> ... </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test2 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> .. </tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
    <tr> 
      <td> Test3 </td> 
      <td> .. </td>
    <tr/>
    <tr> .. </tr>
 </tbody>
```

I need to have a list of strings Test1, Test2, Test3. I tried to do the following in Ruby

```
elements = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")
for x in elements
   puts x.findElement
```

This does not seem to printout the Test1, Test2, Test3.Since I am not familiar with ruby, I tried the following in Java and it seems to work.

```
 List<String> inOneStatement = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]"))  
.stream().map(WebElement::getText)   
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

How could I do this in Ruby?

Answer (score 1):

You should try as below in `Ruby` :-

```
elements = driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]").map(&:text)
# => [" Test1 ", " Test2 ", " Test3 "]
```

**Edited** :- implement `wait` until all `elements` present as below :-

```
wait = Selenium::WebDriver::Wait.new(:timeout => 10)
elements = wait.until { driver.find_elements(:xpath, "//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]") }

elements.each do |el|
  puts el.text 
end
```

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: This does not seem to work. What is returned seems to be empty

Comment: @JonnyPeppers make sure provided `xPath` is correct just `$x("//tbody/tr[1]/td[1]")` paste this at browser console and see what it will return.. if it returns array with that element which you want then you should try to implement some `wait` until all elements available on the page then try to find.